# Python - printing dictionaries without commas

Tags: python, dictionary

I am procesing an music `API`and writing results to a file, like so:

```
for val, track_id in zip(values,list(track_ids)):
    #below
    if val < threshold:
       data = {"artist": sp.track(track_id)['artists'][0]['name'], "track":sp.track(track_id)['name'], "feature": filter_name, "value": val}
      #write to file
      with io.open('db/json' + '/' + user + '_' + product + '_' + filter_name + '.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
           f.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

data is printed as follows:

```
}{
    "artist": "Radiohead", 
    "feature": "tempo", 
    "track": "Climbing Up the Walls", 
    "value": 78.653
}{
    "artist": "The Verve", 
    "feature": "tempo", 
    "track": "The Drugs Don't Work", 
    "value": 77.368
}{
```

the bottleneck is that, further down the code, I try to evaluate this file with `eval`, and it generates the error:

```
  File "<string>", line 6
    }{
     ^
```

how do I insert this `'`comma to separate the dicionaries?

Comment: Where is the loop you are using to write multiple dictionaries to the file at once?

Comment: @Kevin there you go, I've edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write JSON data. If that's the case you can simply dump your dictionary to a file using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. You should first append all your data objects into a single `music` list. You can then encode that list to JSON and write it to a file.

```
import json

music = [
    {
        "artist": "Radiohead", 
        "feature": "tempo", 
        "track": "Climbing Up the Walls", 
        "value": 78.653
    },
    {
        "artist": "The Verve", 
        "feature": "tempo", 
        "track": "The Drugs Don't Work", 
        "value": 77.368
    }
]

with open('music.json') as f:
    json.dump(music, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump

Additionally, you should NOT be using `eval()` if you can help it; Especially when reading random input from a file. It's incredibly fragile (as you've discovered) but it's also incredibly insecure. Someone could easily put malicious code into a file you're evaluating.

Instead, you should use [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load) to load the JSON from the file. This will ensure the file is properly formatted JSON and it does all the heavy lifting for you.

```
with open('music.json') as f:
    music = json.load(f)
```

Comment: could you please edit your answer so as to explain why my `json.dumps` is not working in the code above?

Comment: `json.dumps` returns a string `json.dump` writes to a file. dumps is usually used for printing json or transmitting it, like an API would.

Comment: @data_garden Your `json.dumps` is working fine. The problem is the missing `,`. One way of circumventing this is to collect all data in a list and only at the end write them to a file. For that purpose you can use `json.dump(...)`or `f.write(json.dumps(...))`. The other option is of course to simply write a comma `f.write(",")` in each loop iteration except the last.

Comment: The advantage of using `json.dump()` of the whole list of data would be that you do not need `eval` at the end but can rather use `json.load()` to get the reconstructed python data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sounds great. but could you please post an answer correcting the code using `json.dump()`?

Comment: @data_garden I did 20 minutes ago. Refresh your browser. ;)

Comment: @Soviut I see. but your `music` variable is my intended output. how can I use this as an input argument if I don't have the data structured in this fashion yet?

Comment: @data_garden you need to group your `data` dictionaries into a list. The reason your output is invalid is because you're just appending individual dictionaries to a file; That's not valid JSON format.

Comment: @Soviut and how do I group `data = {"artist": sp.track(track_id)['artists'][0]['name'], "track":sp.track(track_id)['name'], "feature": filter_name, "value": val}`into a `list`?

Comment: There are many ways to add to a list, but the `.append()` will probably do the trick.